# XMLHttpRequest() does not give the DOM that I can see from Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, fetch, screen-scraping

I am trying to fetch information from the body text of a website using the XMLHttpRequest() API. However, its response DOM is not complete and it leaves out some of the content of the website.

```
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.massimodutti.com/us/men/sale/suits-up-to--70%25/black-slim-fit-
textured-wool-blazer-c1745942p8934849.html?colorId=800&categoryId=1745942", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var res = xhr.response;
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(res, "text/html")
  }
}
```

Is there a way to modify the http request to access all of the information on the website?

Comment: I assume the missing HTML content is generated by Javascript. You will have to use something like https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/ or https://github.com/microsoft/playwright or something like that to inspect that

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can use those web-scraping API's from within a chrome extension?

Comment: You can open the site inside an iframe and use a *content script* to extract the info after a timeout.